# Create contents of div using :before and :after

Tags: html, css

I have a single `div` element which I want to insert content into depending on it's class.

I am able to insert 2 elements into this `div` using the `:before` and `:after` attributes in the CSS, but I need to be able to insert at least 5 elements.

Here's what I have for 2:

```
div {
  background: blue;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  padding: 0;
  display:table-cell;
  vertical-align:middle;
  text-align: center;
}

div:after {
  content:'';
  display:block;
  border:1px solid #000;
  width:40px;
  height:40px;
  margin:5px auto;
  background-color:#DDD;
}
div:before {
  content:'';
  display:block;
  border:1px solid #000;
  width:40px;
  height:40px;
  margin:5px auto;
  background-color:#DDD;
}
```

Is there any way I can create extra `:before` and `:after`? Something like `div:after:after`.

Comment: The `content` property, despite it's name should NOT be used to add/show **actual content** but is intended for styling or adding certain effects. The answer to your question is, however, no...there are no additional pseudo-elements possible.

Comment: @Paulie_D "... should NOT be used to add/show actual content ...": Is that due to [accessibility concerns](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::before#accessibility_concerns), or are there additional reasons?

Answer (score 3):

**Nope, Sorry you can't**

**Useful to read :** http://css-tricks.com/use-cases-for-multiple-pseudo-elements/

Just add some element inside your element

**HTML :**

```
<div>
    <div>
    </div>    
</div>
```

**CSS :**

```
div:after {
    content:'1';
}
div > div:after {
    content:'2';
}
```

Answer (score -3):

As Paulie_D comments you can't get :after:after in CSS.

Although you could do it in jQuery by [Chaining](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_chaining.asp)

```
$("div").prepend(" *before* ").prepend(" *before before* ").append(" *after* ").append(" *after after* ");
```

See [JSFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/qGU8S/)

Although it **uses jQuery** it's a bit more *valid* a solution, as really you should just use :before and :after CSS selectors for **styling**.

Comment: I didn't, but perhaps it's better to replace the `*before*`/`*after*` phrases with an HTML/jQuery element.

Comment: @Hashem, hard to do if I don't know what he wants to append prepend, that would be writing his code for him.

Comment: @Sam If they are able to use jQuery they could insert content properly instead of using pseudo-elements. This answer is a little superfluous.